# Using JavaME to get a file's MD5 checksum

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I am trying to use J2ME to get the md5 checksum of a downloaded file.

I haven't been able to find anything that shows how to get the md5 checksum of a file in J2ME, all I can find is in java's MessageDigest which I can't use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a "ready-to-go" solution for MD5 calculation against a file, but RIM's [MD5Digest](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.6api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/MD5Digest.html) class should be able to get you what you need.